# Clear transaction & items before submitting to prevent duplicate E-Commerce data in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking into using (Universal) Google Analytics to track e-commerce transaction data, and would like to put my call to send the transaction data on my thank you page after the user completes the checkout process. I'm learning that many people who do this have issues with duplicate transaction data being submitted when a page refresh happens. I was wondering if immediately before my transaction and item data, could I just call ga('ecommerce:clear'); so that it clears the transaction if it had already been submitted, resulting in only one version of my transaction when I submit it to Google?

Answer (score 0):

**maguidhir**, I am afraid that reloading the page with e-commerce tracking code would send the duplicate transaction anyway as it would get created again.

There is an [interesting article by Matt Clarke](http://techpad.co.uk/content.php?sid=247) that deals with this in 3 different ways.

You can also use Google Tag Manager and make sure the [e-commerce request gets send only once per session](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/universal-analytics-fire-script-just-per-session/). Make sure though that you include Transaction ID as one of the condition, because technically you **could make two e-commerce transactions during one session.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I'm not clear on how ga('ecommerce:clear'); fits into the picture, then. At what point could I use it to clear transactions and items?

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but checked with few other people and ecommerce:clear basically is "Empty cart" function. Mainly used by dynamic one-page websites or so. So it's not related to preventing duplicated in any way.